# Is it possible to merge multiple `iCal` calendars that are imported via URL together to one calender in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, meetup

Meetup.com provides `iCal` calendar for individual meetups. It doesn't provide a shared iCal calendar that contains all meetup events but only a shared meetup list for the meetups where one clicked <kbd>I attend</kbd>.

I would like to have one calendar in Google Calendar that mixes together multiple meetups.

Is it possible to do this in Google Calendar?

Can I combine calendars together?

Comment: I just found your question. Maybe I had the same: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/98872/a-calender-with-all-meetup-events-from-all-meetup-groups-i-joined/98873#98873

Answer (score 1):

Best solution I've heard of so far is to create a separate email address and add all the iCal to that email's calendar and then that would function as a combined calendar.

Later, I've ended up using this really cool Ruby Gem which builds a combined calendar as a web-app, given iCal feeds and works with Meetup.com groups too. They also have great documentation. The final result is a combined calendar and a combined ICS feed, which I presume you can copy into the calendar. I'll keep you updated.

You can see an example below. Look at the bottom of the page for the combined iCal feed which you could add to Google Calendar:

http://christchurch.events.geek.nz/

You can see find the project here:

https://github.com/Aupajo/almanack

Comment: So I've just done this, but it's not a full solution because although all the events appear on my calendar for my events@domain.com calendar - they are not actually marked as one of my calendars :-( So I need to duplicate all events so that they appear as one of my calendars. Unfortunately not a completely automatic solution (yet). But at least I can create a single calendar and just manually duplicate all the upcoming events. If I could create a script whoch does that maybe I win

Comment: You can add this information in answer itself.